# How to do a Fourier transform on input from a microphone and obtain the average amplitude of a certain frequency range

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, sound, visualization

I'm building a sound visualizer with LED strips controlled by python, and I'm trying to learn how to use `pyAudio` to perform rapid Fourier transforms on live mic input and obtain the average amplitude of a certain range of frequencies.

How do I open a sound stream and consistently update the current amplitude (say, a variable called "`amplitude`") of a given frequency range with the live FFT data? I have set up all the hardware and all the basic `pyAudio` functions work so far.

Comment: You can grab a chunk of data using the example PyAudio code here: https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#record-example. Next, you can use numpy.fft.fft to compute the FFT of the most recent data chunk. If you are interested in a frequency range $(f_1, f_2)$ you can look at FFT numbers $\lfloor Nf_1/f_s \rfloor \leq n \leq \lceil Nf_2/f_s \rceil$ where $N$ is the FFT length and $f_s$ is the sampling rate.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the frequencies you're interested in, you might be better off just calculating the power / energy at those frequencies rather than using a full FFT.

The best algorithm to do that is probably the [Goertzel algorithm](http://www.mstarlabs.com/dsp/goertzel/goertzel.html).  There is a python implementation of that [here](https://gist.github.com/sebpiq/4128537), and a related SP.SE question [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/failed-to-implement-goertzel-algorithm-in-python/6065#6065).